# Ошибка при редактировании datagridview c подключенной MySql базой данных. При попытке сохранения появляется ошибка

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview

При попытке редактирования datagridview появляется ошибка "The CommandText property has not been property initialized."
Код программы:

```
    using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SD = System.Data;

namespace DBredaction
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
            DataSet ds;
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter;
            MySqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder;
            string connectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=catalog;Uid=root;pwd=;charset=utf8;";
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM employee";
            public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
            dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

            using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);

                ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                // делаем недоступным столбец id для изменения
                dataGridView1.Columns["Id"].ReadOnly = true;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        //public MySqlConnection mycon;
        //public MySqlCommand mycom;
        //public string connect = "Server=localhost;Database=catalog;Uid=root;pwd=;charset=utf8;";
        //public SD.DataSet ds;
        //public MySqlCommand mycon2;otchestvo

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try { 
            using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
                commandBuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
                adapter.InsertCommand = new MySqlCommand("", connection);
                adapter.InsertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@imia",    MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "Имя"));
                adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@familia", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "Фамилия"));
                adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@otchestvo", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "Отчество"));
                adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@telephon", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 11, "Телефон"));
                

                MySqlParameter parameter = adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.Int16, 0, "Id");
                parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                adapter.Update(ds);
            }
        }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("DB CONNECT");
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection lost");
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
            }
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].NewRow(); 
            ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
    }
```

[image: Оформление программы]
[image: Сама ошибка]

Comment: `new MySqlCommand("",` почему пусто?

Comment: здесь должно быть название хранимой процедуры которая в качестве входных параметров  принимает имя, фамилию, отчество и номер телефона пользователя и возвращает его id, но я не знаю как его создать в myphpadmin